# Windows "copy as path" to open a file in python

Tags: python, filenames

I am having a very simple problemm I guess.
I am trying to open a file in Python pasting windows "copy as path" option

When I paste into Python console I get

```
"F:\AVALIACAO-PC-08-04\Liberacao-antes-tubo-reto\analise\2014-12-16_15-23-25.mag"
```

in order to open the file I need to have this

```
fname='F:\\AVALIACAO-PC-08-04\\Liberacao-antes-tubo-reto\\nnalise\\2014-12-16_15-23-25.mag'
```

How can I manage to remove `"` and add `\` ?

I did managed to remove the " with fname.replace but failed with the \

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can just paste it as a raw string, that is

```
fname = r"F:\AVALIACAO-PC-08-04\Liberacao-antes-tubo-reto\analise\2014-12-16_15-23-25.mag"
```

Change `'` to `"` doesn't really matter as Python accepts both variants.

But if you really want to change `"` to `'` then you can do

```
fname = fname.replace('"',"'")
```

Comment: How is the line with `fname.replace` relevant to this question?